# How do I run CMD.exe as administrator

Tags: vb.net

Have been successful in running a DOS command using the contents of 2 text boxes.  The issue that I am trying to find a resolution for is………….

How do I run with elevated rights (as an Administrator)

Can anyone help me?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Shell($"cmd.exe /c {TextBox1.Text} {TextBox2.Text}")
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate: `How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running an application as Administrator using Shell() is not possible (unless the target file is set to always run with Administrator access).

Instead, use `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process.Start()`:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
psi.Verb = "runas" ' aka run as administrator
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
psi.Arguments = "/c " & TextBox1.Text & TextBox2.Text ' <- pass arguments for the command you want to run

Try
  Process.Start(psi) ' <- run the process (user will be prompted to run with administrator access)
Catch
  ' exception raised if user declines the admin prompt
End Try
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!   I have used the above in my test project and it works perfectly.